# BeautifulSoup iter over multiple XML tags, extract list of string

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, iterator

```
# Sample XML file.
xml = """
<1 sno=1>
    <2>
        Some content
    </2>
    <2>
        Some other content
    </2>
    <2>
        Some more contents
    </2>
</1>
<1 sno=2>
<2>
        Some content
    </2>
    <2>
        Some other content
    </2>
    <2>
        Some more contents
    </2>
</1>
<1 sno=3>
<2>
        Some content
    </2>
    <2>
        Some other content
    </2>
    <2>
        Some more contents
    </2>
</1>
"""
```

This is the sample XML file; I want to process all the <1> tags.

1. First I need to find all the 1 tags,
2. Second, get the contents as a list. I want the <2> to be of separate list element. 
   e.g. I expect a list like `['<2>','some content','</2>' .....]`
           and not like this `['<2>Some content</2>' , ....]`

_

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

xml = BS(xml)
xmlList = []
for line in xml.1:
    xmlList.append(line)
print xmlList    

# To grab multiple '1' tags:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

xml = BS(xml)
xmlList = []
for line in xml.findall('1'):
    xmlList.append(line)
print xmlList
```

displays a list like `['<2>Some content</2>' , ....]`, which I do not want.

If I use `find_all()` statement to grab all '1' tags, the result is same. How to overcome this?

Comment: That is invalid xml ([names cannot start with digits](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-NameStartChar)) so no xml parser - `bs4` included - *should* actually parse it.

Comment: @roippi I think it is just an example the OP tried to make. I think we can safely think of `1` as `a` and `2` as `b` for example. Though I'm still not sure what is the desired output. Well, I see it, but it is a strange thing to want to have.

Comment: Its just an example, i cannot come up with the tags. So its just an example. sorry for confusion

Comment: @agconti - OK understood.

Comment: Guess there is no other option as no one responded. Thanks anyway. I will use regex to process the XML data and then mine the contents. :) Guess that's the only option available.

Comment: @alecxe: I believe this is doable. Maybe use `lxml` for parsing and maybe throw in `BS4` for good measure? `lxml` will fix the tags better, but `BS4`'s tag manipulation can be thrown in. It is weird, but seems like an engaging prospoect for me. Challenging, even. Regex is another way, Bala, but I doubt it's as nice to use. :)

Comment: @Nanashi good points, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what about just slicing the end off before adding to the list?

```
for line in xml.findAll('1'):  #also should be findAll() vs findall()
    xmlList.append(line[:-4])
```